# Find the limit of the multivariable function $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. I want the limit of this function as $(x,y)$ approach $(0,0)$. My try is to approach $(0,0)$ by two ways:
$y=x$ and $y=x^2$. If we do so, we get the same result for both, i.e $f(x,y)$  approaches 1. My question is whether this result is correct or not. Using direct substitution, I get something else.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: One more advantage from having a more detailed title is that now the list of related question contains questions which are much closer to yours than originally. Checking similar questions can be often useful when trying to solve some problem. (Sometimes it even happens that you can find exactly your question in the list of related questions.)

Answer (score 3):

Substitution $y=mx$ will give the limit as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$, which takes different values for different $m\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, limit does not exist.

Comment: Does it mean the function is not continuous there.

Comment: @user41736 No, it is not continuous for any assigned value of the function at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

The method you have followed can be used to show that the limit *does not exist*. If you find two curves passing through the origin, it does not mean that from *every* direction, the limit will be the same.

This is similar to proving anything in mathematics, a single counter example is enough to *disprove* it, but no number of examples are enough to prove it.

In your case, both $y=x$ and $y=x^2$ give the same limit, but that is not enough. As @Saibal 's answer shows, plugging in $y=mx$ shows that the value will be different for different values of $m$. Hence, the limit does not exist.